# select value from android spinner and display button

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to set reminders. There is a spinner with 5 values (1,2,3,4,5). Let's say if user selects 3 from the spinner there should be 3 "Add Time" buttons displayed. Similarly if user selects 5, five "Add Time" button should be displayed.

User presses "Add Time" button and time picker will be displayed to select time for the reminders. I've created spinner through xml from res/string folder and set an array of 5 item (1,2,3,4,5). I don't know to display these "Add Time" buttons as per the selection of value from the spinner.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions/guidance.

Thanks a lot...

```
package com.example.medicationreminder;

import jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.config.ZXingLibConfig;
import jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.integrator.IntentIntegrator;
import jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.integrator.IntentResult;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.medicationreminder.InteractiveArrayAdapter.ViewHolder;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MedInfo extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button daily, weekly, mScanBarcode;
    private Handler  handler = new Handler();
    private ZXingLibConfig zxingLibConfig;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_med_info);

        mScanBarcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Barcodescanner);
        mScanBarcode.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.med_info, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == mScanBarcode)//When scan barcode button is clicked
        {
            IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MedInfo.this, zxingLibConfig);//Intent that opens camera for scanning through zxing Library
        }
/*      else if(v == weekly)
        {
            Intent weekly = new Intent(MedInfo.this,Weekly.class);
            startActivity(weekly);
        }   */
        else if(v == daily)
        {
            Intent daily = new Intent(MedInfo.this, DailyMed.class);
            startActivity(daily);
        }
    }

    //The method that cathes the result after scanning is done
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) 
        {
            case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
                IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,
                        resultCode, data);
                if (scanResult == null) 
                {
                    return;
                }
                final String result = scanResult.getContents();//scanned result
                if (result != null) 
                {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            showScannedResult(result);//opening pop up showing scanned result
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
    //Pop up dialog showing scanned result
    private void showScannedResult(String result)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scanned Result")
                .setMessage(result)
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do things
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

//Array list for selection of Days


    public class Weekly extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate1(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
            getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

      private List<Model> getModel() {
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        list.add(get("Monday"));
        list.add(get("Tuesday"));
        list.add(get("Wednesday"));
        list.add(get("Thursday"));
        list.add(get("Friday"));
        list.add(get("Saturday"));
        list.add(get("Sunday"));
        // Initially select one of the items
        list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        return list;
      }

      private Model get(String s) {
        return new Model(s);
      }

// Spinner item selection and add button

      public class spinning extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

        LinearLayout list;
        Spinner spinner;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_med_info);
            spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list);

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.dose_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        public void addButton(int number){
            list.removeAllViews();
            for(int i = 0; i<number;i++){
                Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                button.setText("Add Time");
                list.addView(button);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,
                long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(i){
            case 0:
                addButton(1);
                break;
            case 1:
                addButton(2);
                break;
            case 2:
                addButton(3);
                break;
            case 3:
                addButton(4);
                break;
            case 4:
                addButton(5);
                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
    }
}
```

Medinfo.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/android"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MedInfo" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MedName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name of Medicine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Barcodescanner"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/MedName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MedName"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Scan Barcode" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Barcodescanner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Barcodescanner"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Dose per day"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:entries="@array/dose_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/dose_prompt" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner" android:id="@+id/list">
</LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkMon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
        android:text="Mon" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkTue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkMon"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkMon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/AddTime"
        android:text="Tue" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkWed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkTue"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkTue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Wed" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkThur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkWed"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkWed"
        android:text="Thur" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkFri"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkTue"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:text="Fri" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkSat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkFri"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkFri"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkTue"
        android:text="Sat" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkSun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkSat"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkSat"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkWed"
        android:text="Sun" />
<!-- 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="Add Time" /> 
-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Medication Reminder</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_med_info">MedInfo</string>
     <string name="dose_prompt">Choose a Dose</string>

    <string-array name="dose_arrays">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </string-array>

    <string name="check_Monday">Monday</string>
    <string name="check_Tuesday">Tuesday</string>
    <string name="check_Wednesday">Wednesday</string>
    <string name="check_Thursday">Thursday</string>
    <string name="check_Friday">Friday</string>
    <string name="check_Saturday">Saturday</string>
    <string name="check_Sunday">Sunday</string>


    <string name="title_activity_daily_med">DailyMed</string>
    <string name="title_activity_weekly">Weekly</string>
    <string name="title_activity_daily__addtime">Daily_Addtime</string>
    <string name="title_activity_interactive_adapter">InteractiveAdapter</string>
    <string name="title_activity_interactive_array_adapter">InteractiveArrayAdapter</string>
    <string name="title_activity_barcode_scanner">Barcode_scanner</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

ActivityMain.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

LinearLayout list;
Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ativity_main);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.number, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void addButton(int number){
    list.removeAllViews();
    for(int i = 0; i<number; i++){
        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        button.setText("Add Time");
        list.addView(button);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    switch (i){
        case 0:
            addButton(1);
            break;
        case 1:
            addButton(2);
            break;
        case 2:
            addButton(3);
            break;
        case 3:
            addButton(4);
            break;
        case 4:
            addButton(5);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
}
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner" android:id="@+id/list">
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="number">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>
```

Hope, it will be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks a lot VortexHeatkiller for your response. I implemented the code, it runs without an error but does not display "Add Time" buttons as per the selections in spinner.

Comment: Can't post code... it's not letting me to post it. Tried every options.

Comment: I can't help you if I don't see how you have implemented the code. Try to edit your start post and paste code there.

Comment: Alright.. here it is, figured how to write code here... I have also implemented bar code scanning in it.

Comment: ok, the code seems to be doing well. Can you post XML code of your activity_med_info layout? Maybe there something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses.. I appreciate it.